# I cannot find my app by its name on Google Play but I can find it by package name?

Tags: android

I developed an app and uploaded it onto Google Play. When I search for it by name it does not show my app, but if I search by my package name like "com.percentage" it shows my app. Can anyone please help me. How can I make my app searchable by its name and not by package name?

Answer (score 2):

Google Play can take several hours to update it's search index.

Your app is searchable by title by default, and key words are picked up from your description. So the best way is to flesh out your description enough to have a decent amount of key words. But if you overdo it, you could get banned for key word spamming.

As for not being able to search right now, just wait. The longest delay I've seen is around 8 hours, though it usually only takes a couple for the index to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

It does take usually three hours for google play to update their listings from when you upload it.  Your product name that you put in on the description page is the name of the app as its going to be found.  In the description right "keywords:" + keywords to describe your app for better marketing and findability.